# Conditional routing configuration

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I would like to have a responsive application. It should have a different navigation on a small screen (series of screens to drill down to detail page) and on a big screen (left panel + details on a single page).

In effect, I would like to load different components and have a different routing configuration depending on the screen/window size. And I would like to be able to switch between them dynamically, as the window is resized above/below a certain threshold.

Since routing in Angular2 is defined on a component level, my idea was to create a root-level component, which would conditionally (ngIf) include either bigScreen.component.ts or smallScreen.component.ts. The routing itself would then be defined in bigScreen/smallScreen components. This does not seem to work though.

I created a [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/cjFR0jJ7N6zUdVPsiO1T?p=preview) to showcase. It's basically a copy of heroes navigation from the Angular tutorial. I created additional component *app/container.component.ts* which is bootstraped as a root component. It then embeds AppComponent (root component in the tutorial), which contains the routing configuration.

This produces an error on the console:

```
Error: Component "AppContainer" has no route config.
```

Looks like I have to create navigation config in my root component if the nested components have one. Is there a way around it to achieve what I need? Or should the responsive routing be implemented differently?

Comment: I have the same question and stumbled upon this post, Kindly let me know if you have managed to find a solution. Thanks in advance. Its been a long time since this post so hopefully Angular 2 now supports it out of the box, but not able to figure it out.

Answer (score 4):

In the new router (`>= RC.3`) https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/router/index/Router-class.html#!#resetConfig-anchor `resetConfig` can be used

> ```
> router.resetConfig([
>  { path: 'team/:id', component: TeamCmp, children: [
>    { path: 'simple', component: SimpleCmp },
>    { path: 'user/:name', component: UserCmp }
>  ] }
> ]);
> ```

You might need a dummy configuration to initialize the router on app startup or use [How to pass parameters rendered from backend to angular2 bootstrap method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37611549/how-to-pass-parameters-rendered-from-backend-to-angular2-bootstrap-method/37611614#37611614) to delay the initialization until the route configuration is prepared.

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11437#issuecomment-245995186 provides an **RC.6** Plunker

Comment: Thanks for the hint. It does not work for me though. The reset config seems to reload the routes definitions, so that the subsequent navigation uses the new settings. But it does not affect the component tree being currently displayed. And I need the live reload, so that the components adjusted to the screen size are displayed.
The link to the doc is broken. The new one is https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/Router-class.html#!#resetConfig-anchor

Answer (score 0):

```
let routeMobile = [{path:'/', name: 'Home', component: MobileHomeComponent},
  {path:'/hero/:id',      name: 'Detail',   component: detailComponent}];

let routeDesktop = [{path:'/', name: 'Home', component: DesktopComponent}]

function checkForMobile(){
  //returns true for mobile
}
let finalRoute = checkForMobile() ?  routeMobile : routeDesktop;  

@Component({ ... })
@RouteConfig(finalRoute)
export class AppComponent { }
```

If you desperately want it to be responsive too, just reload the page on `"resize"` event.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @GauravMukherjee. Reload on resize is no-go for me. It seems I have three options: implement a service to detect location changes and the view logic with ngIf, implement my own router or use another framework (e.g. Aurelia), where it is possible to dynamically switch the routes. I am a bit disappointed Angular2 does not support this kind of scenario out of the box.