# Angular 2 load data before rendering the app

Tags: typescript, angular

In my main component's ngOnInit I do get some global settings :

```
ngOnInit() {
   this._service1.initGlobalData()
   this._service2.initGlobalData2()
}
```

these 2 calls initialize _service1 and _service2 which are then used in several different places in my app.
I would like to be sure these 2 calls are done before starting rendering my application.

Is there any specific way to do it in Angular 2 ?

The only solution that comes up to my mind would be to set a spinner up based on the promises returned by these two init calls.

Comment: Just to add to Nguyen's answer: You can also refer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37611549/how-to-pass-parameters-rendered-from-backend-to-angular2-bootstrap-method

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41619443/how-to-call-an-rest-api-while-bootstrapping-angular-2-app

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is not very popular but I think the easiest way it to just wrap your template with `*ngIf="data"` then the template will only be rendered after `data` has a value assigned.

The router (depending on what version you're using) might have lifecycle callback that allows to delay the component to be added until a promise is resolved.

Answer (score 4):

You can use https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/APP_INITIALIZER-let.html

An example (take a look at the bottom of the page): https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/%40angular/router/src/common_router_providers.ts

Answer (score 3):

Normally my team and I use ngIf to render the content when it's ready.
Something like:

```
<div *ngIf="_service1">
   // content for _service1
</div>
<div *ngIf="_service2">
   // content for _service2
</div>
```