# How to implement Runtime configuration for my app?

Tags: angular

For my App I need **runtime configuration** (docker architecture), so I cannot rely on Angular's environment mechanism. **So I created my own config file that I read like this:**

```
@Injectable()
export class ConfigService {

  config;

  constructor(private http: Http) {
    this.loadConfig();
  }

  loadConfig() {
    this.http.get('./../../../assets/config.json')
      .map((res: Response) => res.json())
      .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error')) 
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.config = data;
      })
  }
}
```

This worked well until I tried to access my config during another component's nngOnInit(): config was undefined at the time. **I realized that the observable had not returned.**

1. Is there a **better approach** to solve the runtime configurability ?
2. How can I make sure the config has been loaded **before I use it elsewhere ?** I thought of solutions like a boolean "isLoaded", or even checking if "config" is undefined - but there must be a better way.

Any idea is welcome

Comment: I solved my problem following this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41619443/how-to-call-an-rest-api-while-bootstrapping-angular-2-app

Answer (score 0):

[This post](https://juristr.com/blog/2018/01/ng-app-runtime-config/#runtime-configuration)tells you how to hook into Angular's APP_INITIALIZER constant to solve this problem.