# Angular Page is Not loading after adding APP_INITIALIZER (Configuration Service)

Tags: angular

As mentioned at **[how-to-call-an-rest-api-while-bootstrapping-angular-2-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41619443/how-to-call-an-rest-api-while-bootstrapping-angular-2-app?answertab=active#tab-top)**, I have implemented the changes and able to see the config loading logs.

But Page is not loading, when I remove APP_INITIALIZER provider from app.module.ts, then the page is loading.

Did anyone face this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Silly Me...

I forgot to set the `resolve(true)` at ConfigService.  After setting `resolve(true)`, Page is being loaded.