# Angular - Where To Run Initialization HTTP Requests After Login

Tags: angular, http, rxjs, angular-routing

I have a design question about when and where to send multiple `HTTP` requests for initialization information (types, business dates etc) that will be displayed in all components.

Right now I have my `auth.guard` that after the user signs in retrieves the user claims and authorization rules and then checks if the user is authorized.  The guard returns `true` or `false` based on their roles.   From here I have around 10 info `HTTP` calls that are the same for most of my components.  But I want to keep these `HTTP` calls out of my `auth.guard` since they can run in the background as the component loads and it should not be the `auth.guards` responsibility.

I am also using a shared service that uses `BehaviorSubjects` so multiple components can subscribe to the value.

So,  my main question is, what is the best practice so that after the `auth.guard` returns `true`, run `x` amount of `HTTP` requests and update the shared service.  This needs to be applied to any number of components.

Also been looking at route resolvers which might solve the issue, but I would rather save the data to a shared service instead of return the data to the component and have to wait.

Another piece that makes this a little more complicated is that I have my 10 `HTTP` calls spread throughout multiple services, so if I have a shared service it would need to inject all of the other services.

Comment: just run them in the component constructor?

Comment: @mast3rd3mon I only want to run these HTTP requests **once** after login.  So If I navigate from component to component don't rerun the requests.  Plus, they are the same so I want to have it in one place to reduce code duplication

Comment: then have a global service in which you call them?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41619443/how-to-call-an-rest-api-while-bootstrapping-angular-2-app?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: @deezg this happens after the user logins, so a good time after app Initialization.  The user needs to be authenticated to get the http responses.

Comment: aha...well then maybe a `canDeactivate` of the login component might be a good candidate? Triggering a global service at that point.