# Angular 2 - Loading Component

Tags: angular

I have a basic loading component that displays a spinner and fetches a remote config file required by the rest of the app to function.

Is there a way to route all routes through the loading component first so the config data is loaded?

Or is there another recommendation to guarantee some common logic (fetching remote config) is executed prior to any routes being loaded regardless if the user enters the url to a specific route?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37611614/217408 might work for your use case

Comment: I think `CanActivate` would also help.

Comment: @micronyks right, it depends on how often it is supposed to be loaded or checked (only once or for every route) https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#guards

Comment: It should only be called once, but needs to be called regardless which route a user comes in on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guards & `CanActivate` were the solution I ended up using, and it worked well.