# Angular2 APP_INITIALIZER nested http requests

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I've been trying to use the `APP_INITIALIZER` during the bootstrap process to load some configuration data (similar to [How to pass parameters rendered from backend to angular2 bootstrap method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37611549/how-to-pass-parameters-rendered-from-backend-to-angular2-bootstrap-method), [Angular2 APP_INITIALIZER not consistent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39725724/angular2-app-initializer-not-consistent), and others).

The problem I'm facing is that I need to make 2 requests, the first one to a local json file where a URL resides, then the request to that URL to get the actual configuration.

For some reason however the startup is **not** delayed until the promise resolves.

This is the load method that gets called via the `APP_INITIALIZER`

```ts
public load(): Promise<any> 
{
  console.log('bootstrap loading called');
  const promise = this.http.get('./src/config.json').map((res) => res.json()).toPromise();
  promise.then(config => {

    let url = config['URL'];
    console.log("loading external config from: ./src/" + url);

    this.http.get('./src/' + url).map(r => r.json()).subscribe(r => { this.config = r; console.dir(r);});
  });
  return promise;
}
```

And here is a complete [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/aowws0G21HttXbItQjUW) demonstrating the problem (check the console output).

Obviously I'm missing an important understanding of the concept.

How can I get the app to wait for both requests to return before the component is loaded?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1) Return promise

```
export function init(config: ConfigService) {
  return () => config.load();
}
```

2) Keep order

```
public load(): Promise<any> {
  return this.http.get('./src/config.json')
        .map((res) => res.json())
        .switchMap(config => {
          return this.http.get('./src/' + config['URL']).map(r => r.json());
        }).toPromise().then((r) => {
          this.config = r;
        });
}
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/dDuZcj9Syzigjh5rN41b?p=preview)**

or withour rxjs operator

```
public load(): Promise<any> {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const promise = this.http.get('./src/config.json').map((res) => res.json())
      .subscribe(config => {
        let url = config['URL'];
        this.http.get('./src/' + url).map(r => r.json())
          .subscribe(r => { 
            this.config = r;
            resolve();
          });
      });
  });
}
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/zmX84n7nwuOtcIJOSE9K?p=preview)**

Comment: The `switchMap()` was the missing link for me, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You are not returning any promise in the provided plunkr:

```js
export function init(config: ConfigService) {
  return () => {
    config.load();
  };
}
```

should actually be:

```js
export function init(config: ConfigService) {
  return () => config.load();
}
```

or

```js
export function init(config: ConfigService) {
  return () => {
    return config.load();
  }
}
```

Comment: You are correct, that was from an earlier attempt and I forgot to change it back, thanks for catching that!