# How to serialize initialization of angular2 components?

Tags: angular, angular2-services

Currently when bootstrapping the app component angular2 doesn't wait for completion of all the lifecycle phases.

The following method start end sequence will be printed to the console:

> AppComponent.ngOnInit() - START
>
> SearchComponent.ngOnInit() - START
>
> AppComponent.ngOnInit() - END

How can for the completion of all the lifecycle phases of app component be waited for, so that the sequence looks as follows:

> AppComponent.ngOnInit() - START
>
> AppComponent.ngOnInit() - END
>
> SearchComponent.ngOnInit() - START

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? What code produces this output?

Comment: I'm trying to initialize two services during application startup prior to the initialization of all components so that the components can use the cached results in ngOnInit or in the constructor.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37611549/how-to-pass-parameters-rendered-from-backend-to-angular2-bootstrap-method/37611614#37611614. Perhaps also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36271899/what-is-the-correct-way-to-share-the-result-of-an-angular-2-http-network-call-in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not control the lifecycle callbacks.

You can use

- `*ngIf` to not show parts of the application until the condition changes to `true`. If you wrap the content of the root component template with such an `*ngIf="isLoaded"` no component except the root component will be created.
- [Route guards](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#guards) to prevent route navigation until a condition becomes `true`.
- `APP_INITIALIZER` that prevents initialization of your Angular2 application until the returned `Promise` resolves. See [How to pass parameters rendered from backend to angular2 bootstrap method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37611549/how-to-pass-parameters-rendered-from-backend-to-angular2-bootstrap-method/37611614#37611614) for an example
- Observables to notify about state changes and also to cache responses to prevent multiple calls. See [What is the correct way to share the result of an Angular 2 Http network call in RxJs 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36271899/what-is-the-correct-way-to-share-the-result-of-an-angular-2-http-network-call-in) for an example.

The chosen way for my problem was the usage of the APP_INITIALIZER. Services utilizing the router (such as Angulartics2) can't be used, because at this point the router hasn't been initialized yet.
Below is an example code using async-await.

```typescript
@NgModule({
imports: [
    HttpModule,
    routing,
    SharedModule.forRoot()
],
providers: [
    {provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/'},
    {provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
        useFactory: (appModule:AppModule) => async () => {
            await appModule.init();
        }, deps: [AppModule], multi:true}
],
declarations: [AppComponent],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {

    constructor(private service:Service) {
    }

    // tslint:disable-next-line:typedef
    async init() {
        await this.service.init();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are these approaches known to work with async-await, too?

Comment: I don't know details about async-await in TS, but if it doesn't it's probably a bug in the async-await.

Comment: I see. When I use the APP_INITIALIZER approach which seems to be best suited for me, then I see the following: Uncaught Error: Provider parse errors:
Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency! ApplicationRef_: in NgModule AppModule

Comment: You can work around that by injecting the `Injector` and getting the dependency by `this.myDep = injector.get(MyDependency);` instead of injecting `MyDependency` directly.

Comment: Now I see the following error: zone.js:344Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot read property 'componentTypes' of undefined ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: Cannot read property 'componentTypes' of undefined(…) TypeError: Cannot read property 'componentTypes' of undefined

Comment: Sorry, no idea. Can you reproduce in a Plunker?

Comment: I think so, but maybe you've got an idea based on the fact that the error only occurs with custom services.

Comment: AFAIR the error means that "something" is wrong in your code. Perhaps an import or similar.

Comment: I've narrowed it down to:  {provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
        useFactory: (injector:Injector) => {
            injector.get(Router);
        }, deps: [Injector]} // the router causes the exception even if it won't be injected/used in the service which I want to use.

Comment: Hard to tell without a working repo case to investigate.

Comment: I wasn't able to make the Plunker work but it's not related to `APP_INITIALIZER`. If I remove that whole provider I still get the same error.

Comment: Try it now, please

Comment: With the provided SampleService in the plunker it works in my environment, too. The main difference seem to be the dependencies which my LocationService has.

Comment: Apparently all dependencies must be listed under "providers" despite all of them have been imported under "imports" in modules - this is both, redundant and error-prone. Is there a way to do it in a simpler way? I've just updated the plunker: If you remove "SecondSampleService" from the providers you have the failure.

Comment: That shouldn't be necessary, except for lazy loaded modules which get their own root scope and their providers don't become available to the root scope of the non-lazy loaded modules.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126231/discussion-between-andras-hatvani-and-gunter-zochbauer).