# Wait for jQuery document.Ready() in angular2 service

Tags: jquery, angular, angular-cli

I have an angular2 (with angular-cli) app that will exist inside a web page of a website that is provided by a CMS (DotnetNuke).  This web cms uses the services framework of jquery to generate a validation token for api calls to the website's "backend".  As a result I can not generate any web api calls to the website until I have this validation token.

I created a service to handle the calls to the website's api(s).  In the constructor of the service I try to set the token in the following way *(the ServicesFramework Object has a function called getAntiForgeryValue which returns the token )*:

```
@Injectable()
export class ApiService {

    private http: Http;

    constructor(http: Http) 
    {
        console.log('dnn service constructor');

        $(document).ready(function () {
            this._dnnSF = $.ServicesFramework(804);
        });
    }

    getRequestVerificationToken(): any {
        return this._dnnSF.getAntiForgeryValue();        
    };
}
```

The **getAntiForgeryValue()** of the ServicesFramework just returns the jQuery **__RequestVerificationToken** for ajax calls to .net web api endpoints.  *This is just for explanation.*

### **The Issue:**

The other components that get this service injected are calling the **getAntiForgeryValue()** before the document.ready is complete in the services's constructor and therefore I am getting:

> Cannot read property 'getAntiForgeryValue' of undefined

**Question:**
Can someone help me work out a strategy with angular2 where I can wait for this validation token to be provided before the angular app runs or how to wait in the service for the constructor to complete.

Thanks in advance

Comment: why the down vote?  Come on people, if you down vote then provide a reason.

Answer (score 1):

That error means that: $.ServicesFramework is not defined. You need to find a way to inject it into the Angular world. One way (not recommended but quick) is to declare it in the global scope outside of Angular:

`window.framework = $.ServicesFramework;`

Then declare it on the top of your service:

`const framework;`

Then in your constructor you can do this:

`constructor(http: Http) 
{
  this._dnnSF = framework;
}`

List I said this is quick and dirty. The better way would be to inject the external component when you bootstrap your Angular application.

Comment: thanks Boyan, I was previously using opaque tokens and injecting the  $.ServicesFramework in the providers of the root ngModule.  But the provider was complaining that the value of $.ServicesFramework was undefined.  It seemed to not want to provide/inject an object that was yet undefined.  That is why I tried to change my approach.  I will give yours a try.

Comment: Your initial approach was the better one. If you want to inject the module on bootstrap, but it's not available right way, you need to do it by using a promise that waits for the external component to be loading, and in the promise callback, bootstrap your application and inject the ready object. More on this from another answer.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37611549/how-to-pass-parameters-rendered-from-backend-to-angular2-bootstrap-method