# Bootstrapping an Angular 2 application with remote data

Tags: angular, webpack, bootstrapping, angular-module

I'm attempting to setup an application where my Angular client app communicates with an API server. In this API server I have various environment variables declared to match it's different environments (currently *development* and *production*).

The Angular client should HTTP-get a portion of these env variables that are being served on an API endpoint `http://myserver.com/api/client-config`. I understand this should occur before the application is bootstrapped, but I don't understand where or how I should include the HTTP call.

**app.module.ts**

```
...
import firebaseConfig from './config/firebase.config'; 

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        VrtVideoPlayer,
        VrtAppsComponent,
        SubtitlesComponent,
        RangeSliderComponent,
        listPipe
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule, 
        FormsModule,
        NgbModule,
        VgCore, 
        VgControlsModule, 
        VgOverlayPlayModule, 
        VgBufferingModule,
        HttpModule,
        AngularFireModule.initializeApp( firebaseConfig() ),
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            { path: 'subtitles', component: SubtitlesComponent },
            { path: '', component: SubtitlesComponent },
        ]),
    ],
    providers: [ExtBrowserXhr],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

import '../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';
import './common/styles/styles.scss';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent {
}
```

**bootstrap.ts**

```
import {platformBrowserDynamic} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import {AppModule} from './app.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

**More specifically** 
The following import:

> import firebaseConfig from './config/firebase.config'

relies on environment variables declared in the API server environment. Can I simply make my HTTP GET-request here? This wouldn't be an ideal solution if my application requires the config object served by `http://myserver.com/api/client-config` elsewhere. Is it possible to bootstrap my application with this data, and if so - What's best practice regarding this?

Comment: An approach http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37611549/how-to-pass-parameters-rendered-from-backend-to-angular2-bootstrap-method/37611614#37611614

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to answer my own question; In this particular case I decided that utilising a client-side implementation of environment variables was a proper way to address my problem, as opposed to attempting to import the ones defined on the server environment.

I run my client using Webpack. A perfect example of a possible way to implement client-side environment variables can be found here:

[angular2-webpack-starter/wiki](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/wiki/How-to-pass-environment-variables%3F)