# Send http request before sending other http requests angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-http, angular2-jwt

I need to get jwt token via http module then make other requests with this token in header. How I can make delay of app initialization till token get request resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.http.get(...)
.map(response => response.json())
.flatMap(response => this.http.get(...).map(response => response.json())
.subscribe(response => this.result = response);
```

You can use [How to pass parameters rendered from backend to angular2 bootstrap method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37611549/how-to-pass-parameters-rendered-from-backend-to-angular2-bootstrap-method/37611614#37611614) to delay app-initialization.