# Angular2 & Rest API -> sessions

Tags: rest, http, angular, angular2-http

I'm trying to develop a web app in which the users need to login. So I need to store their Session ID.

I would need to make an http get to the Rest API, get the session ID if the user is signed in, and then return this Session ID. But the angular2 script would need to wait until it gets this Session ID before executing the rest of the code...

Is their a way to make that possible ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37611549/how-to-pass-parameters-rendered-from-backend-to-angular2-bootstrap-method/37611614#37611614

Comment: it worked thanks ! But I finally realized that it can't work like that. I need to store the session in the client side. So I'm now wondering how I could tell to my server which session sending the request.
Is their no other way than sending the session as a GET Param ?