# Ensure json configuration is loaded in Angular2

Tags: json, angular

I need to load and process some configuration items from a JSON file on the server.

However, I need to be sure that the processing is completely done before I continue to load the application, i.e. I want that part of the loading to be synchronized.

Is there an out-of-the box solution for this, aside from using a sync XHR?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37611549/how-to-pass-parameters-rendered-from-backend-to-angular2-bootstrap-method