# Applying a Resolve to root component in Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-resolve

In Angular2 we can use `Resolve` as follows:

```
import { UserResolver } from './resolvers/user.resolver.ts';

export const routes: RouterConfig = [
  {
    path: 'users/:id',
    component: UserComponent,
    resolve: {
      transaction: UserResolver
    }
  }
];
```

But how can I best apply a resolver to run on, for example, my `app.component.ts`? Perhaps when the website loads for the first time, *no matter* what page is first loaded, I'll always need to get the user data first (for example). So how can I have this resolver apply lower down the hierarchy of routes?

Comment: Perhaps you want something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37611549/how-to-pass-parameters-rendered-from-backend-to-angular2-bootstrap-method As AngularFrance said, a resolver can only be used for components added by the router, which the route component isn't.

Comment: Maybe you can use APP_INITIALIZER https://hackernoon.com/hook-into-angular-initialization-process-add41a6b7e

Answer (score 3):

I've been wondering about the same thing.

Turns out that if the initial request to the site is for a path which has one of its components guarded by a resolve, the resolve will run *before any component* in the tree is instantiated. Including `AppComponent`.

Now the problem is that `AppComponent` itself is NOT a routed component and as such it cannot access the resolved data. Maybe you could inject `ActivatedRoute` into `AppComponent` and access the data via the current route's `children` but it seems hackish.

What I typically do is set up a resolve (or `CanActivate` guard) *at the root of my route hierarchy* to fetch that initial data. The data itself is returned by a service and wrapped inside a `ReplaySubject`. This guarantees that 1) the data will be shared among all subscribers; 2) the code fetching the data will only be executed once.

In other words:

- I use an **observable** to fetch the async data once and share it among all the parts of my app that need it.
- I rely on the **route system** to trigger the execution of that observable as early as possible in the app lifecycle.

(But I'm not using the route system to fetch the data and share it.)

**Update to answer the comments:**

You have to introduce a dummy parent route to support the guard, for instance:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',  // This is the "root route"
    component: PageShellComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      { path: 'home', component: PageHomeComponent },
      { path: 'inbox', component: PageInboxComponent },
      { path: 'settings', component: PageSettingsComponent }
    ]
  },
];
```

The parent route is the "root of the my route hierarchy" and its guard `AuthGuard` gets executed for ALL child routes in the application. As you can see, the parent route has an empty path and `PageShellComponent`'s template only contains `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`. The sole purpose of this route is to support the guard(s).

I should add it doesn't feel very idiomatic and I'm not sure this is the best way to go.

Comment: This seems like a working solution. However, I don't see where "at the root of my route hierarchy" is. Say I have `/home` and `/contact`, I don't have a, say, "root" route which is triggered on both `/home` and `/contact`. Could you provide an example?

Comment: @AngularChef please show where you set up the resolver/guard "at the root of your route hierarchy". Thanks!

Comment: This is not working for me, one difference that I have is that I have no direct children but I ase the RouterModule.forRoot

Comment: You also don't need to include a `component` for this to work. Without a `component` this becomes like a shared group `canActivate`