# How to pick an Angular 2 service for a component at runtime

Tags: javascript, angular, dependency-injection

I have a requirement, based on configuration parameters, pick a specific service as an injectable to the component. All the examples I see, really use a specific service and use it at component construction time.

Is there a way to perform this injection at run time?

Comment: Yes. `injector.get()`. RTM, https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html

Comment: thanks for the quick and accurate reply, i think I can use that scheme based on configuration parameter values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a factory that returns a different instance depending on some configuration

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [
    ConfigService,
    { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useFactory: loadConfig, deps: [ConfigService] },
  ],
  ...
```

see also [How to pass parameters rendered from backend to angular2 bootstrap method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37611549/how-to-pass-parameters-rendered-from-backend-to-angular2-bootstrap-method/37611614#37611614)

```
function myServiceFactory(config:ConfigService) {
  switch(config.someProp) {
    case 'someValue': return new ClassA();
    default: return new ClassB();
  }
}

@Component({
  providers: [
    { provide: MyService, useFactory: myServiceFactory, deps: [ConfigService] }
  ],
  ...
```

Comment: where is MyService and ConfigService are defined? Part of angularCore?

Comment: No, that's just example names of custom classes