# Angular 2: Use LOCAL_ID from remote

Tags: angular, angular2-services

In my angular app, I want to set `LOCALE_ID` for currency and other pipes. I receive `LOCAL_ID` from remote service. I need to set it to my angular app. This is how I am doing it:

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { LocaleService } from './locale.service';
import { LOCALE_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent }   from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  providers: [
    LocaleService,
    { 
          provide: LOCALE_ID,
          deps: [LocaleService],
          useFactory: (localeService: LocaleService) => {
            return localeService.getLocal().then(local => {
              console.log(local);
              return local;
            })
          }
    },
  ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

`LocaleService` is my service get the local from backend. Here's a sample snapshot of my `LocalService`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class LocaleService {

    constructor() { }

    getLocal() {
        //return 'en-In';
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                resolve('en-In');
            }, 3000);
        });
    }
}
```

The challenge, is when `getLocal` method is synchronous i.e. when I hard code the value, it works fine but when I make it `async` it's not working. I need to use `local` returned by `getLocal` service. Not sure what I am missing. As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37611614/2879146) I should be able to use it. Here's the plunkr to [play](http://plnkr.co/edit/rstcTgLsqqrcxOhNxtUn?p=preview). Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?