# Function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported function

Tags: angular, typescript, lambda

I'm using APP_INITIALIZER in my app and I have it setup in app.module.ts as follows with the necessary imports:

```
@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [ ..., ContextService, { provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: (context: ContextService) => () => context.load(), deps: [ContextService], multi: true } ],
  ...
})
```

I get the following error when I build fresh (ng build -watch), *subsequent builds work fine*.

> ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically.
>   Function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or
>   lambda with a reference to an exported function (position 24:46 in the
>   original .ts file), resolving symbol AppModule in C:/.../app.module.ts

I have tried moving `() => context.load()` into an exported function in the same file as so:

```
export function loadContext(context: ContextService) {
    return () => context.load();
}
```

...then altered the  providers section of @NgModule:

```
@NgModule({
      ...
      providers: [ ..., ContextService, { provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: (context: ContextService) => loadContext(context), deps: [ContextService], multi: true } ],
      ...
    })
```

The build still fails initially as above with the same error. Subsequent builds work fine.

How do I solve this initial build error?

Comment: `useFactory:loadContext` https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11262

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Move the inline closure to a function:

```
function loadContext(context: ContextService) {
  return () => context.load();
}

@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [ ..., ContextService, { provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: loadContext, deps: [ContextService], multi: true } ],
  ...
})
```

See also [How to pass parameters rendered from backend to angular2 bootstrap method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37611549/how-to-pass-parameters-rendered-from-backend-to-angular2-bootstrap-method/37611614?noredirect=1#comment73084432_37611614)

Comment: Glad to hear. Thanks for the feedback :)