# Angular resolve with separate modules

Tags: angular, routes, angular-routing, ng-modules

How can I activate a RouteGuard or Resolve on child routes **within another module**?

#### Example Scenario:

I have an application which has many separate modules, each defining their own routes. Consider these modules definining the following routes:

```
Module1 -> ['/a', '/b', '/c']
Module2 -> ['/d', '/e', '/f']
```

Now, I need to make sure that every route within the application has the following resolve:

```
resolve: { config: AppConfiguration}
```

We can use:

```
{ path: '',  component: AppComponent, resolve: { config: AppConfiguration}  }
```

However that achieves nothing -`/` executes the resolver, but `/a` does not.

The only way I've found to make sure routes `/a`, `/b` and `/c` call the resolver, is if I make them children of the root as follows:

```
AppModule -> [ { path: '', component: 'MainComponent', resolver: {..}, children: [
    ...Module1Routes
    ...Module2Routes
] ]}
```

But by doing that this means the application is no longer structured in the way recommended by the Angular documentation, `RouterModule.forChild()` is no longer used in other modules.

I'm sure this is a pretty common use case - is there a better way?

Comment: Is there a reason why config is a resolver? Should it be reinstantiated on every route change?

Comment: I have another case which makes sense - had to change the variable names because it's super secret and stuff :)

Comment: Also, if you have it in the root, the objective is to NOT have it re instantiated on every route change, but rather loaded once when root is loaded, (ie; when I press F5 or restart the app)

Comment: So going from /a, to /b to /c would call the resolver once, but I can still go to /c and it would call the resolver. Attaching the resolver to each route individually would call it three times.

Comment: Yes, `children` is the way to do this. But if you want them to be feature modules and use `forChild`, the whole idea breaks apart - you decouple things from root module, yet you try to couple them again via common resolver. Doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Probably you should pick names better, so it would provide better idea of what is your case and how to treat it properly. From my understanding, AppConfiguration should be just a provider on root injector.

Comment: @estus Let's say you want to call a /profile call every time the user reloads the app, (but not when navigating between routes) on all routes except the login. I think that would fit the scenario I described.

Comment: Ok, I guess it looks similar to 'configuration' case, more or less. The solution may differ a bit if there are details that stayed out of scope of the question, but the options stay the same as in suggested answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `AppConfiguration` is supposed to be a singleton that is shared by all routes, there are two common patterns to do that.

Considering that a major benefit of resolvers is to access data that was unwrapped from asynchronous resolver as `activatedRoute.snapshot.data.resolverName`, one way is to use a singleton service that is unwrapped by all resolvers, e.g.:

```
@Injectable()
class Config {
  data: IConfig;
  data$: Observable<IConfig>;

  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  load(forceReload = false) {
    if (!this.data$ || forceReload) {
      this.data$ = this.http.get('...')
      .map(res => res.json())
      .do(data => {
        this.data = data
       })
      .publishReplay(1)
      .refCount();
    }

    return this.data$;
  }
}
```

`load` method returns an observable with cached server response that is functionally equal to a promise. But since it is known that observables are natively used by a router, it is natural to use them in this context.

Then all resolvers can return `config.load()` and ensure that request will be performed only once (unless it is called like `config.load(true)`):

```
@Injectable()
class ConfigResolver {
  constructor(private config: Config) {}
  resolve() {
    return this.config.load();
  }
}

...
{ path: ..., component: ... resolve: { config: ConfigResolver } }
```

It is possible to make code DRYer and provide a function or a class to add `config` resolver for all routes, though this is not recommended since this approach is not compatible with AoT. In this case WETter is better.

Another way is to use [poorly documented `APP_INITIALIZER` provider](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/APP_INITIALIZER-let.html), which is explained in detail in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37611549/how-to-pass-parameters-rendered-from-backend-to-angular2-bootstrap-method). While route resolvers postpone route change, `APP_INITIALIZER` works in the opposite way and postpones application initialization.

It is multi-provider and should be defined in root injector:

```
export function configInitializerFactory(config: Config) {
  return () => config.load();
}

@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [
    ...
    Config,
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: configInitializerFactory,
      deps: [Config],
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
...
```

No resolvers have to be involved because data has been already resolved during app initialization.

Fortunately, `data$` observable is already being unwrapped to `data` in `Config`, so resolved data is already available on injection as `config.data`.

Comment: @David Yes, APP_INITIALIZER is good for that. I guess you're judging from A1 experience where route resolvers were the only recipe for delaying init process. Luckily, this was fixed in A2.