# Angular 2 different configs for one project

Tags: javascript, angular, jenkins

I have one Angular 2 project with some configuration files for access to microservices. This project deploying and building automatically by Jenkins to different servers. That proccess could be showed like this [image]

The question is: How to create custom configuration for each server. Option with
 `environment.{$server_name}.ts` not good, because in my case count of servers can be huge.

**UPDATE:**

Configuration file containe microservice url, example:

```
export const MSConfigAPI = {
  protocol: 'http',
  baseUrl: 'some-url',
  version: 'v1',
  port: '8082',
  clientId: 'api_user',
  clientSecret: 'pass',
  getUrl: () => {
    return MSConfigAPI.protocol + '://' + MSConfigAPI.baseUrl + ':' + MSConfigAPI.port + '/' + MSConfigAPI.version + '/';
  }
};
```

Also i could have other configuration files that needes only for particular server.

My appication is CMS, so i want to have one source code, but for each project i want to change local configuration files.

On each server placed result of `ng build --prod --aot`, so plain css, js and other content.

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: What does the configuration contain, and what's running on each server? Is there  a node instance, for example?

Comment: You could have a pre-build step which generates `environment.ts` based on whatever.

Comment: @msanford Hi! I updated the question, could you check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to consider exposing a web service on each server with all the configuration properties for your application. Then you can use the [APP_INITIALIZER](https://angular.io/api/core/APP_INITIALIZER) to call the web service on startup and store these configuration properties.

The biggest benefit of this is that you only need 1 build for all different environments. Also, changing configuration can be done without rebuilding the project.

Check [this Plunker example](https://embed.plnkr.co/295SxTOZEZUbiyrhAKh2/) of how to use it.

**Edit**: You might also want to check [this SO topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37611549/how-to-pass-parameters-rendered-from-backend-to-angular2-bootstrap-method) if you find that this method fits your needs. (*Just be wary of some older examples using Angular RCs instead of the final version*)