# ANGULAR Error encountered resolving symbol values statically

Tags: node.js, angular

When I try to run `npm run server`
I get the error :

```
ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported function (position 64:19 in the original .ts file), resolving symbol AppModule in C:/Users/*****/src/app/app.module.ts
```

webpack: Failed to compile.

Here is the content of my app.module.ts :

```
    import { NgModule, ApplicationRef } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {SharedService} from './shared.service';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import {MaskedInput} from './+front/masked-input.directive';

/*
 * Platform and Environment providers/directives/pipes
 */
import { routing } from './app.routing'
// App is our top level component
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { APP_RESOLVER_PROVIDERS } from './app.resolver';
import { AppState, InternalStateType } from './app.service';

// Core providers
import {CoreModule} from "./core/core.module";
import {SmartadminLayoutModule} from "./shared/layout/layout.module";
import {UrlPermission} from "./UrlPermission/urlPermession";
import {Http, HttpModule, RequestOptions, XHRBackend} from '@angular/http';
import {MyCustomHttp} from './interceptor';
import {AuthService} from './AuthService/AuthService';
// Application wide providers
const APP_PROVIDERS = [
  ...APP_RESOLVER_PROVIDERS,
  AppState
];

type StoreType = {
  state: InternalStateType,
  restoreInputValues: () => void,
  disposeOldHosts: () => void
};

/**
 * `AppModule` is the main entry point into Angular2's bootstraping process
 */
@NgModule({
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [ // import Angular's modules
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    CoreModule,
    SmartadminLayoutModule,
    routing
  ],
  exports: [
  ],
  providers: [ // expose our Services and Providers into Angular's dependency injection
    // ENV_PROVIDERS,
    APP_PROVIDERS,
    SharedService,
    UrlPermission,
    AuthService,
    MaskedInput,
     {
      provide: Http,
      useFactory: (backend,options) => new MyCustomHttp(backend, options),
      deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions]
    },

  ]
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(public appRef: ApplicationRef, public appState: AppState) {}


}
```

I thought it was a node version problem so I downgraded NodeJS from 10 version to 8 version. But the error is always the same
It worked fine on my old computer. I don't know what changes or what commands should I tape. or how should I change the app.module.ts

Any help please?
Thank you

Comment: I believe your useFactory should be returning a function per https://stackoverflow.com/a/37611614/10747134
Also see: https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-providers#factory-providers

Since the error line/col is your useFactory implementation.

Comment: Can you post the code of `MyCustomHttp`?

Comment: Also, `HttpModule` is deprecated, you should start using `HttpClientModule`

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner Thank you. Here is the code of `MyCustomHttp`
`@Injectable()
export class MyCustomHttp extends Http {

  constructor(_backend: ConnectionBackend, _defaultOptions: RequestOptions) {
    super(_backend, _defaultOptions);
  }
  
  request(url: string | Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    let token = sessionStorage.getItem('Token');
    if(token==null){
      token='';
    }
      if (typeof url === 'string') {

        const headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);`

Comment: `options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
        
        //console.log('Url is string', options.headers.get('Authorization'));
      } else {
        url.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);
        //console.log('Url is Request', url.headers.get('Authorization'));
      }
    
    return super.request(url, options);
    }

  
}`

Comment: Which Angular version are you using?

Comment: "version": "4.0.1"